# How to retrieve the records from a same column in table for different purposes using joins in SQL

Tags: sql-server

My tables look like this:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName    DateOfBirth MaritalStatus   Gender  Email   InsertedDate    UpdatedDate dateofjoining
1   Sai Kumar   15/10/1993  Unmarried   Male    S@gmail.com 2014-01-01  2014-01-01  2014-01-02 00:00:00.000
2   Venky   rachipudi   16/10/1991  Unmarried   male    v@gmail.com 2014-02-02  2014-02-02  2014-02-02 00:00:00.000
3   Manoj   Kumar   16/10/1990  Married male    m@gmail.com 2014-03-03  2014-03-03  2014-03-04 00:00:00.000
```

Second table

```
TeamID  EmployeeID  TeamLeadID  ProjectID
  1         1            3         1
  2         2            3         2
```

Comment: Nice data...what is your actual question?

Comment: i am expecting employee name and team lead name from my first table joining with second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two joins to get the output you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e1.LastName, 'NA') + ', ' + COALESCE(e1.FirstName, 'NA') AS employee_name,
       COALESCE(e2.LastName, 'NA') + ', ' + COALESCE(e2.FirstName, 'NA') AS team_lead_name
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN employees e1
    ON t2.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN employees e2
    ON t2.TeamLeadID = e2.EmployeeID
```

Here `table2` is what you labelled `second table` in your question, and `employees` is the first table containing information about each employee (including team leads).

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.firstname + ' ' + t1.lastname as EmployeeName, 
       t3.firstname + ' ' + t3.lastname as LeaderName
From t1 left join (select distinct EmployeeID,TeamLeadID from t2) t2 on 
     t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID left join t2 as t3 on
     t2.EmployeeID = t3.EmployeeID
```

Hope this what you're looking for.

Comment: its show error in t3 pls check it.thank u for your response